# How can I color individual points with Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

I am basically trying to color my points separately based on value, I have tried setting up thresholds but its not working.

I have data which ranges from 0-4 and I want to color each point separately based on what the value is

E.G - 1 = Blue, 2 - Green

Also tried gradient but they only give me options on min, max , last and selecting any option colors all the dots the same color

Answer (score 0):

You can set color for timeseries. Instead of one query use 4 queries and select there only timeseries with particular value (1,2,3,4) + use unique name for eqch timeserie. Then you can define color for each timeserie.

Answer (score 0):

With MetricsQL you can compose your queries so that only one discrete value from 0 to 4 is returned.

```
# query1
ts_data == 0

# query2
ts_data == 1
```

or if you have a different set of metrics providing your discrete values, filter the series with `and` logic for each discrete value:

```
#query1
ts_data and 
status_code == 0

# query2
ts_data and 
status_code == 1
```

You can then use overrides to set *Standard Options > Color Scheme* to a unique single color for each query.